# Outer Join SQL on having query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which (in my system) gets the total number of members who have more than 6 memberships....

```
select count(*) as MemberCount from (
   SELECT count(membership.memberid) as MembershipCount from Membership, Package
   WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
   AND membership.DiscountPercentage != 100
   AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
   AND membership.MembershipStateId != 5
   AND Membership.LocationId = 1
   group by memberid
   having count(membership.memberid) > 6
) NonTrialMemberships
```

What i need to do is left outer join the "having" part of it with a temporary table so i can get a listing of the number of members who have more than 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 memberships

```
having count(membership.memberid) > 6 <------(OUTER JOIN THIS)
```

I have created a temporary table to use as the join but not sure how to use it.  I have also seen that using an in memory table may be more efficient than a temp table...

```
create table #Temp
(
Num int, 
)

DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @total int = 10

WHILE @i < @total
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    Insert Into #Temp values (@i)
END

select * from #Temp


select count(*) as MemberCount from (
    SELECT count(membership.memberid) as MembershipCount from Membership,     Package
    WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
    AND membership.DiscountPercentage != 100
    AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
    AND membership.MembershipStateId != 5
    AND Membership.LocationId = 1
    group by memberid
    having count(membership.memberid) > 6
) NonTrialMemberships




If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp
End
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using your #temp.

```
select #temp.num, count(*)
from #temp
left join  
    (
    SELECT count(membership.memberid) as MembershipCount from Membership, Package
    WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
    AND membership.DiscountPercentage != 100
    AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
    AND membership.MembershipStateId != 5
    AND Membership.LocationId = 1
    group by memberid
    having count(membership.memberid) > 1
    ) ntm 
on ntm.MembershipCount > #temp.num 
group by #temp.num
```

definitly it will count users with 11 memberships in every >1, >2, ..., >10 group, as requested.

Comment: Thanks for this..i think you have nailed the join for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a different way

```
SELECT [MembershipCount], Count(1) FROM
(
        SELECT count(membership.memberid) as MembershipCount from Membership,     Package
        WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
        AND membership.DiscountPercentage != 100
        AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
        AND membership.MembershipStateId != 5
        AND Membership.LocationId = 1
        group by memberid
)
order by Count(1) Desc
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I think you should modify this query to add a `group by` on the outer query. Also, I think the OP  wanted only `WHERE MembershipCount <= 10`.

Comment: This will count every user only once which is inconsistent with  OP's "get a listing of the number of members who have **more than** 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 memberships".

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the counts, and get the count of each of those (sounds weird, but it's actually very simple):

```
SELECT MemberCount, Count(*)
FROM
(
       SELECT count(membership.memberid) as MemberCount
       FROM Membership, Package
       WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
       AND membership.DiscountPercentage != 100
       AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
       AND membership.MembershipStateId != 5
       AND Membership.LocationId = 1
       group by memberid
       having count(membership.memberid) > 6 
) t
group by MemberCount
order by MemberCount
```

You mentioned that you want to get the number of members who have 1, 2, 3, etc. memberships.  If that is the case, you will want to remove the following line from the query:

```
having count(membership.memberid) > 6
```

Doing so will include a count of all counts (again, sounds weird), which seems to be your requirement.  Please leave a comment if you would like clarification or if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: If there are no members who have 6 memberships then this will not "count" that number correctly..

Comment: @ChristopherPettigrew Please read my entire answer.  I explain that by removing the "having count(membership.memberid) > 6" line, you will include all counts of members...

Comment: This will not work even when removing it.  If i have members with 1,2,3 and 4 memberships and a final member with 10, then the group by will ignore the counts...[link](http://postimg.org/image/4j4a6pdh3/)

Comment: @ChristopherPettigrew What do you mean when you say "the group by will ignore the counts"?

Comment: Click the link in the above comment for picture

Comment: @ChristopherPettigrew I did click the link and I did look at the picture, but I still don't understand what you're trying to say - or what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I thought you wanted to know how many people you have with each number of memberships.  For example "10 people with 1 membership, 20 people with 2, 105 people with 3, etc., etc.".

Comment: [Click Here](http://postimg.org/image/jbk2ik6ev/) for the result set that i was expecting based on Serg's answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109828/discussion-between-christopher-pettigrew-and-stan-shaw).